# How to add POI to Here Maps

Tags: here-api

I am not able to find an endpoint in Places ( Search ) API to add a new POI, Can you please tell me which entry point should be used for POST to add a Place to HERE MAPS? 
I would also like to know if the following API will let me add a missing place/business to HERE Maps :
https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/map_feedback/map-feedback-about-a-missing-place

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (I work for HERE, but do not know everything), the endpoint you found for Map Feedback would be how you would add information about a missing resource.